# Reflowing content for responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to use Adactio solution for changing the flow of content when creating a responsive design - http://adactio.com/journal/4780/
but get a butg in firefox where you can no longer tab through the links in the page, see http://jsbin.com/axobun for an example.

Can anyone think of an alternative solution or fix for this problem?

Comment: unable to recreate this problem, tested in FF 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Recreated with FF7.0.1 in OSX - think this is browser specific